# How to increase /home space in Debian?

Tags: debian, unix

I'm using Debian OS. In this VM my home folder space is full so I allocated extra hard disk space of 120 GB. Now total available space is 220GB. By editting the Vm setting, i expanded the harddisk space

How do I allocate this extra space to home folder? I'm not understanding where the allocated hard disk space went. I'm new to Unix. Please help me in understanding this.

I have already posted the question in below url. Since this s the first time i'm posting here I couldn't add images

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702255/how-to-increase-home-space-in-debian?noredirect=1#comment107400595_60702255

Comment: It's most likely unallocated space. Boot into a Live Gparted ISO and extend your partition into the new space. If you have a separate partition for the home, extend that partition instead.

Comment: Did you extend the first virtual harddisk or add a second one?

Answer (score 0):

First, to get answer you need to provide information. Instead of posting images, posting output of your commands as (properly formatted) text is always preferred.

Second, from your images in SO I saw, you had your `home` partition on `/dev/sda3`, but there is no info, which device is

> allocated extra hard disk space

You can mount this resource (you made filesystem on it?) into filesystem. If you want this happening automatically, you must make entry into `/etc/fstab` for it.

As far this is VM, I suggest to allocate needed amount disk space, copy all files into it and then remount this resource as new `home`.

**EDIT** According to the comment you need to use some tool to resize your filesystem on partition. I think the simplest is `gparted`

Comment: I have expanded the hard disk space, from 100 GB to 220GB by editing the hard disk space in VM preference settings, Now maximum available space is 220GB. But home folder space is not increased.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understood you correctly, but in order to increase the space available in your `/home` directory, you need to do two things (assuming it is on the separate partition)

1. resize the partition itself (I guess this is what you have done so far)
2. resize the filesystem. If this is not a `/` partition (seems not), you can boot to single user mode, or at least, unmount `/home` - and use the command like `resize2fs` - if this is the filesystem on your partition.